# RegEx Question - Remove everything between : and ~

Tags: javascript, regex

I am having trouble getting a regex to work.  This is the string.

```
"some text would be here and Blah St:39.74908:-104.99482:272~Turn right over here"
```

I need to remove the

```
:39.74908:-104.99482:272~
```

part of the string.  I am using jQuery if that helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var your_string = "some text would be here and Blah St:39.74908:-104.99482:272~Turn right over here";
alert(your_string.replace(/:.+~/, "")); /* some text would be here and Blah StTurn right over here */
```

Comment: You might consider making the ".+" lazy - `string.replace(/:.+?~/, "")`.  That way, if there's ever more text in the string, possibly containing a tilde, it won't be consumed.

Answer (score 4):

```
var str = "some text would be here and Blah St:39.74908:-104.99482:272~Turn right over here";
alert(str.replace(/:[^~]+~/g, ""));
```

Comment: I'd use this one. Would seem to be a little safer.

Answer (score 0):

```
var string = 'some text would be here and Blah St:39.74908:-104.99482:272~Turn right over here'
var string2 = string.replace(/(?::-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?){3}~/g, '')
```

Will replace all instances of :number:number:number~

The numbers can be negative and can have decimals

Answer (score 0):

You don't need an extremely complex regex for this:

```
var str = 'Blah St:39.74908:-104.99482:272~Turn right over here';

str.replace(/:.*~/, '');
```